# Laravel / Eloquent BelongsToMany sync more than one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update multiple relationships at once, however, only the final sync call actually saves to the database in the following code:

```
// find article by ID
$article = Article::find($id);

// Update status relationships
$article->authoringStatus()->sync([$request->authoringStatus]);
$article->publicationStatus()->sync([$request->publicationStatus]); // Only this one syncs

// save the rest of the request data
$article->update($request->all());
```

If I swap the sync statements around, still only the final one saves to the database. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's because sync removes all the records from the pivot table and then inserts the new ones.  The second sync is overwriting whatever is inserted in the first sync.

Comment: Gotcha! I'm using the same pivot table for both status types, need to think of a different approach. Thanks!